# Print a rectangle div with the exact size

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I want to print a rectangle div on a sheet of paper with the exact size to be printed on the paper.
    `<div style="width:15cm;height:10cm;border:1px solid #CCC"></div>`
But,when i try to print this div,the size varies from browser to browser.
What can i do, so that the rectangle div is exactly printed same on the sheet of paper.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really enforce it beyond what you've already done. Printer settings belong to the realm of client computers.

Perhaps your best chance is to generate output in a format designed for printing, such as PDF. But even in that case the user can resize the document.